# Алгоритм ГСЧ генерирующий одинаковые числовые последовательности при одинаковом Seed

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, случайные-числа

В языке есть генератор случайных чисел не привязанный к какому-либо параметру, а надо сделать наоборот.

Сверх сложный не надо, но и совсем простой тоже было бы не желательно.

Comment: язык - javascript?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian некоторые варианты PHP себя ведут так же...

Comment: Ответом является любой [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Разные алгоритмы могут иметь разные свойства. Какие вам надо? Не смотря на кажущуюся простоту, не стоит самостоятельно пытаться их реализовывать, если это не является упражнением в образовательных целях.

Comment: Да язык - js. По поводу свойств - не преследую цели связанные с криптографией, скорее просто генерация мира / имен и т.п.

Comment: В общем я оставил ответ тут, переписал линейный конгруэнтный метод. Если можно посмотрите верно ли.

Comment: Секция Credits на abundant-music.com указывает на [этот Mersenne Twister](https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494).

Comment: @AleksanderK.: отредактируйте ваш вопрос и перенесите информацию из комментариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) может стать приемлемым решением, если нет требований к криптостойкости.

С учетом специфики JavaScript, проще взять параметры генератора, используемые в стандартной функции [`minstd_rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/minstd_rand/) из `c++11`:

```
multiplier = 48271
increment = 0
modulus = 2147483647
```

В случае умножения `multiplier` (48271) на максимальное значение `seed` (2147483646), получается 103661183076066, что меньше максимально возможного безопасного целого числа в JavaScript [9007199254740991](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

```js
var Random = function(seed) {
  seed = (seed || 1) % 2147483647;

  return {
    next: function() {
      return seed = seed * 48271 % 2147483647;
    },

    seed: function(s) {
      seed = s;
    }
  };
};

var random = new Random(1);
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1) {
  console.log(random.next());
}
```

Для сверки результатов можно использовать код на `c++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::minstd_rand g(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        std::cout << g() << std::endl;
}
```

[Ссылка](https://repl.it/CmFW/5) на действующий C++ код. Оба варианта дают в конце последовательности из 1000 итераций одинаковый результат:

```
... 390639274, 1641974594, 429183498
```

Как ограничить результат по диапазону, думаю, вы знаете.

Answer (score 1):

Mersenne Twister или любой линейный конгруэнтный используйте. Можно еще из Кнута взять или из glibc

Comment: К сожалению, это ответ-ссылка, а не ответ

Comment: @Kromster вы, верно, предлагаете написать реализацию десятка пригодных автору ГПСЧ, да еще на непонятно каком языке?

Comment: Я бы предложил рассказать относительно простой алгоритм и дать ссылку на литературу как дополнение, а не ограничиться одной лишь ссылкой.

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил ответить на свой вопрос, возможно кто-то прокоментирует, может я что-то не так сделал.

Использую пример из вики-статьи [Линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Единственное: я исключил отсечение разрядов (вроде) и вместо целочисленного возвращаю дробное число от 0 до 1.0.

```js
var Random = function(seed) {
  var A = 1103515245,
      C = 12345,
      M = 0x80000000;
  
  seed = seed || 1;
  
  return {
    rnd: function() {
      seed = (A * seed + C) % M;
      return seed / M;
    },
    
    seed: function(s) {
      seed = s;
    }
  };
};

var seedInp = document.querySelector('#seed');
var out = document.querySelector('#out');

document
  .querySelector('#rndBtn')
  .addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() {
      var numbers = [];
      var random = new Random(seedInp.value);
      for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        numbers.push(random.rnd());
      }
      
      out.innerHTML = numbers.join('\n');
    }
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<label>Seed:
  <input type="number" id="seed" value="1" />
</label>
<input type="button" value="Rnd" id="rndBtn" />
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: От оригинального алгоритма с википедии далеко ушло..

Comment: Почему? В оригинале: `seed = seed * A + C; return (unsigned int)(seed / 65536) % RAND_MAX;` у меня 
`seed = seed * A + C; return (seed % RAND_MAX) / RAND_MAX;`

Comment: Только вот он начинает отдавать NaN после какой-то итерации... а, seed уходит в Infinity(

Comment: В оригинале 32 битная целочисленная арифметика, поэтому у вас в infinity уходит.

Comment: Исправил, вроде работает. Перепутал вначале.

Comment: Ну если не считать, что это уже самопальный генератор получился, то все ок )

Comment: Еще раз исправил) Теперь вроде в подсчете seed ничего не изменено, только лишь вывод дробный.

Comment: Смотрите, взять хотя бы выражение A * seed. В оригинале результат неявно берется по модулю  4294967296 (как следствие 32-х битной арифметики). Т.е. в оригинале всегда после умножения получается число меньше 4294967296.. В js этого не происходит.